# How do you use an instance variable with mailer in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, instance-variables

I created an instance variable (@user) in the model of a mailer and want to access it in the view? But it's giving me an an error (@user = nil). What's the best way to pass a variable to view (the email body)?

Thanks, Chirag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to access an instance variable in your mailer template then in your mailer model add

```
@body[:user] = user_object
```

The above would create an instance variable @user that can be accessed in your view. You should be able to access user object in your mailer view by doing

```
@user
```

The docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) have examples of alternative ways if you are using multiple formats (text/html).

Comment: Hi, I am a little confused the examples show directly assigning the value @account = recipient for example....does that work instead?  It's not for me...so wondering whether your way of @body[:user] is the way to create @user.

Comment: this gives me the expected "you tried to call [] on nil (@body)" error. @nas - do you advise that this line be @body[:user] = user_object defined above and outside the methods in the mailer model?

Answer (score 4):

I Rails 3 the process is similar:

```
@user = user_object
```

The above would create an instance variable @user that can be accessed in your view. You should be able to access user object in your mailer view by doing

```
@user
```

Note that you need to set this variable before the

```
mail(:from => "info@domain.info", :to => recipient, :subject => "Subject")
```

Comment: "Note that you need to set this variable before the mail(... " - this really helped me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To pass a variable to the view/email body, you send them in via the body method :-) [So, for example](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html), `body :account => recipient` would result in an instance variable `@account` with the value of `recipient` being accessible in the view.